# How to effectively play against an Annie support?

Tags: league-of-legends

Annie has very unfortunately become a fairly popular support. She has high base damage and can nuke with little to no problem with practically no AP items. This is very hard to deal with as an ADC. What sort of counter-play is there when laning against her?

What usually happens is that I just get zoned when she has stun up, or if I do decide to go to farm, she stuns and nukes me easy for the carry to clean up and get fed off of.

Comment: It has been a long time since I've played, but Annie intrinsically is a very aggressive support, which means that she's not very good at protecting her own ADC. I'd wager that a good strategy is to harass the opposing ADC as much as possible, since it doesn't have the normal protection it might be used to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annie's Q refunds the mana if she kills something with it. Unfortunately for support Annie, building Pyromania stacks for free with Q is not nearly as much of an option.

If playing a tanky support, you can bait out the stun. During this time, their ADC will probably attack you; during this time, make sure your ADC attacks their ADC.

Once Annie's stun is down, to restack it, she either has to burn a fair chunk of mana, or wait a pretty long time for E to come off cooldown, or she has to steal some CS. None of these are favourable for her; if you play aggressively when it's down, you can force her to lose mana.

Also, Annie tends to be relatively squishy, especially if her E is not active. She also has no sustain, so while her ADC can heal up poke with lifesteal, Annie lacks that luxury. As Paralytic mentioned, poking her down can force her out of lane rather easily. (Avoid doing this with auto-attacks, though, since her AA range is immense and she will be able to trade back damage.)

It is *extremely* important to time Annie's Flash. If possible, check her masteries to make sure you know the cooldown on her Flash. Play MUCH safer whenever her Flash is up.

Also, be very wary of when she has 3 stacks built up. She can quickly cast E and then an offensive spell to potentially catch you off-guard.

Toward the endgame, Annie support falls off a bit as she has very little utility. Her AoE stun is a glorified Leona ult that does continuous damage, but she remains squishy. ADCs should avoid duelling with her, since the 1.75 second stun is deadly, but a good support with more utility should be able to outscale in the lategame, provided that there is some itemisation against her damage.

Comment: This is kind of what I was getting at but said much, much better.

Comment: I typically find most annie supports to just become a 2nd APC and have the ability to nuke throughout the game, never really falling off at any point.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective anti-Annie combo I have come across is a poke lane. Usually a mobile/pokey ADC combo like a double ADC or heavy DMG blitz or Nid combo.

It is hard to go against an Annie purely because her burst is really strong even when behind. She can stun and combo damage anyone below 50% health with or without items making a true 2v2 impossible to win, for a evenly skilled matchup. The goal with a poke lane is to do so much damage to them that they won't want to engage. This will allow you to rely on a good gank or out farming them.

Answer (score 0):

Not being an ADC, I can't really give you advice specific to ADC. By the way, Schism did that pretty good.

However, I can complement from a support perspective.

First, you need to assess the threat that this Annie represents. Some people do not have in mind how to play uncommon supports, sometimes forgetting to reset their stun. In this case, you can take advantage of this by pressing the lane.

If this is not the case, you will have to do between the stacks.

It is also a good thing to choose the right support to side with (if possible). Supports like Zilean are good for fighting against Annie. He has a long Auto attack as well and can put his bombs at a nice range to. By reaching level 6 you can also tamper with the ability of Annie to burst your ADC using your ultimate.

Good anti-Annie supports might also be Gallio as he builds up nice magic resistance and if he avoids being stun, he can pop his ultimate to protect his carry. Lulu is also pretty good to tamper burst damage, but she might be a bit fragile.

Botlane combats are usually a matter of threat management. You can either increase the threat to match the other side threat or raise your utility to diminish the other side threat.